# "Could not launch Visual studio" error (on Mac)

Tags: c#, ios, macos, visual-studio, xamarin

I updated Visual Studio on Mac and after it tried to start, it told me I need to install Mono and directed me to a web page for that. I installed Mono. Now every time I launch Visual Studio, it just says

> Could not launch Visual Studio
>
> This  application requires Xamarin.Mac native library side-by-side.
> Please download and install the latest version of Mono.

I tried restarting but that didn't help.

What now?

(I'm running the latest macOS, and updated XCode if that matters. Mono is 5.4.0.201.)

**New EDIT:(2022)**

### Users are saying there's a better way than uninstalling and reinstalling. I haven't tested it myself. See comments and answers for more information.

**Previous EDIT:**

Uninstalling and reinstalling is still the only way as the answer suggests, on: 2019:

- March
- July
- August
- September

Comment: Use the VS4M Universal Installer to be sure all the dependancies are installed. : https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/103004/installation-of-visual-studio-for-mac

Comment: @SushiHangover What's **VS4M**?

Comment: VS4M = Visual Studio for Mac

Comment: @SushiHangover Thanks! Am trying that now.

Comment: @SushiHangover It was a good idea. But still the same error.

Comment: davedavee's answer worked for me.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The fastest and easiest way will be to uninstall and reinstall Visual Studio.

Comment: July 2019. Still the only way. This is (getting) ridiculous.

Comment: August 2019. Still the only way.

Comment: July 2020. Still the only way.

Comment: March 2021. davedavee's answer worked for me.

Comment: Jan 2022.  Just uninstalled and re-installed and now it opened.  I did download a version of mono in between.

Answer (score 5):

I have just ran into the same problem. I did follow the alert instructions and installed the newest mono framework from Mono websites (6.10.0). After this still the same issue. So I downloaded and ran VS4M installer and it said, it need version 6.8 of Mono framework and it did offer me to download and install this "update". So i went ahead. Still the same warning after launching VS.

Desperately enough after reading this thread I started looking for uninstall instructions (on official site). I did not want to use the script to auto-uninstall as I rather do it all by myself just for ensuring it will be everything done properly. So manual uninstall said to delete the Visual Studio app from /Application folder first. I did it. And woala: All the sudden the new app called "Visual Studio (old)" appeared (or maybe it was there already but I did not notice? Anyway, it was there). It was certainly weird, but I ran it. And it did work! Working instance of Visual Studio! I did check the updates and there was one for the app only. That was my first step straight after launching. It did download the new update and installed it correctly. Now I have end up with fully working and fully updated version of VS4M!

**Conclusion:**

Use VS4M installer to install all updates and necessarities to run VS4M. After this go to your /Application folder and delete "Visual Studio" app. The "Visual Studio (old)" app should appear. Run this app and update it straight away. (you might have to rename it afterwards from "Visual Studio (old)" to "Visual Studio")

Comment: Deleting the Visual Studio.app and running the Visual Studio Old worked for me.

Comment: This worked for me. I think this should be the accepted answer!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try going to the `Applications` folder? You'll see a `Visual Studio.app` file there and you can run Visual Studio by opening that.

Answer (score 0):

I have sovled the problem by `brew install --cask mono-mdk` rather than `brew install mono`, in case anyone is installing mono through brew.